# map_reduce C++ lamba: candidate not viable single argument

Tags: c++, lambda, mapreduce, c++17, reduce

i wrote a small prog to make map/reduce work in C++.
here the struct:

```
struct Point {
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
};
```

And i want to pick 'x' of each point and multiply them by an int. Then, i want to reduce values with the final lamba (or via std::multiples)

```
std::vector<Point> p = {{10,20},{20,40}};
std::vector<int> p3 (p.size());

auto totalx = transform_reduce(p.begin(), p.end(),p3.begin(), 0.0, [](Point& p){ return p.x * 23;}, [](int a, int b){return a * b;});

cout << totalx << endl;
```

I have this error:

```
main.cpp:28: candidate function not viable: requires single argument 'p', but 2 arguments were provided
conversion candidate of type 'int (*)(Point &)'
```

And i really dont get what i did wrong.

Comment: `transform_reduce` gives a single value, not an output range. What is the purpose of `p3`?

Comment: I thought that i needed to give a temporary list to store the int value. Like a transiant list of integer.
I was wrong....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that you want:

1. To transform all the points from (x, y) to x*23
2. to multiply all of these values

In this case, you should give:

1. Begin
2. End
3. Initial value (in case of multiplication, 1.0 and not 0.0)
4. Binary operation (`std::multiplies<int>()`, or your `[](int a, int b) {return a * b; }`, to reduce between elements)
5. Unary operator to map a single element (In your case, `[](const int number){return number*23;}`)

Overall:

```cpp
auto totalx = std::transform_reduce(p.begin(), p.end(), 1.0, [](int a, int b) {return a * b; }, [](const Point& p) { return p.x * 23; });
```

Note that there is no need for output iterator, since there is a single result.

Comment: I dont get the order of the lambda. So, the reduce function is the third arg, and the map function is that last one.
Its weird ? no ?

Comment: You are right that it is called `transform_reduce` and it receives the reduce function before the transform, but this is the standard...